# Not enough categories for Low Quality Post

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I wanted to review a Low Quality Post

It was **a code only answer**.

These were the options available

- Looks OK if nothing is wrong with this answer
- Edit if you can fix all the problems with this answer
- Recommend Deletion to recommend that this answer be deleted
- Skip if you are not sure and want to go to the next item

Now, since we talk about a code only answer:

- You can't say it looks OK, since it doesn't;
- You can't edit it yourself, since OP knows exactly what he meant
- And obviously it's not "deletion" material.

What I wanted was to leave a comment but, to clear the post from the queue, I would have had to select one of **Looks OK**, **Edit** or **Recommend Deletion**, none of which looks suitable for an answer that simply **Needs improvement from OP**.

Again, in this case it is OP who needs to add details and explain the thought process or what the code does or how exactly does it answer the question.

What should be done in this case?

Comment: It does look okay. It is readable, it doesn't have grammar mistakes. Not being helpful is not something you need to judge when reviewing, that is what *voting* is for.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But the voting buttons are not available in this review queue

Comment: I know, that's why I said *Not being helpful is not something you need to judge when reviewing*. You pick 'Looks OK'. If you want to vote or comment, open it up in a separate tab to follow up, but your *review* is done.

Comment: Open it up in a different tab and vote away, if you feel so inclined.

Comment: And one more thing. The definition for Looks OK is *if nothing is wrong with this answer* which is not accurate

Comment: @Adelin: and there is nothing wrong. Just because it only contains code doesn't mean it is an invalid answer. It is merely not a helpful answer.

Comment: You do have _Needs improvement from OP_. It's right there at the bottom of the post. It's called _add comment_, which might be confusing, though. But it's a feature I often use, sometimes in conjunction with AutoComments.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth after you leave a comment, you also need to clear the post from the queue, with one of looks ok, deletion or edit - and neither seems right

Comment: Looks OK is fine imo. The post is not bad enough to remove, it just could use improvement. It might help the OP in its current form (at least that's how I handle code-only answers).

Comment: @Adelin: You pick 'Looks OK' when it doesn't need deleting or editing. You don't need to delete such a post, and you can't edit it (what would you add?). So your remaining option is 'Looks OK'. It doesn't say 'Looks Great', just merely *OK*.

Comment: I have to say that when I started with the review queues, the "looks ok" button really grated me. While the meaning is clear, now; I remember it felt like I was saying that it was a _good_ answer (e.g. that didn't require additional edits, more development, etc). You learn to go beyond that, but I do think that the labels are not great for new reviewers.

Comment: All that being said, we have users clicking on "looks ok" on steaming turds, so I guess making the labels even friendlier wouldn't particularly help.

Comment: You could see _Looks OK_ as _Meh, not worth editing nor deleting_. It doesn't need to be great. It mainly needs to be intended as an answer (not a comment) and not be spam. That's a pretty low bar, and you could say _Looks OK_ doesn't really describe it well.

Answer (score 1):

> You can't say it looks OK, since it doesn't;

Sure it does.  You've said so yourself that the post doesn't merit deletion, meaning *it's okay*.  That button isn't saying that it's a useful post that is a *high quality* answer.  That would be what upvoting it means.  You're just saying that it meets the minimum standards of the site to the point that it doesn't merit deletion.

Comment: I agree, but in this case shouldn't the definition of "Looks ok" be changed a bit? A code only answer doesn't meet the *"nothing is wrong with this answer"* definition

Comment: @Adelin: but **nothing is wrong with the answer**. Nothing that you need to care about in the review queue.

Comment: @Adelin Where do you see, "Nothing is wrong with this answer" defined?  The tooltip for the button is, "this answer doesn't seem low quality", which isn't great, it should say, "very", or say that it doesn't merit deletion, but tooltips need to be brief.

Comment: @Adelin: if the post doesn't need editing, and it doesn't need deleting, then nothing is wrong *as far as what you are asked to review for is concerned*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I understand what you mean and from here on I'll be able to deal with such posts, but I still think something needs to be changed in this queue for more clarity. At least a link towards a broader definition, if not more clarity in that UI directly